# How to revert: Alt suddenly stopped to help special char creation?

Tags: keyboard, special-characters

I guess I've unintentionally pressed some key combination that changes function of right <kbd>Alt</kbd>.

I want it to change normal Latina letters into special letters (as it is by default).

Comment: Check your keyboard layout (text entry settings). I guess international layouts have additional Latin characters on the 3rd level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have accidentally switched `text entry settings` to other language by following key combination:

<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>

Pressed that again and <kbd>Alt</kbd> is back co-creating special chars.